# How to make DIV scrollable with overflow for iPad/mobile Devices?

Tags: ipad, html, scrollable

i have a scrollable div which has the CSS Attribute overflow. With my iPad i can scroll the content of this div, but there are no scrollbars. Is it possible to show this scrollbars and to use them with no special javascript (jQuery) plugin?

Comment: -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch

Answer (score 0):

You cannot Add Scrollbars. In iPad you can scroll with your 2 fingers. it is better to show full content in mobile devices as `overflow:visible`. if you are using responsive design, this option is better.